# Functions whose Nth derivative are themselves?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I found this [reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4s1gu5/n_functions_that_are_their_own_nth_derivative/) about the question, can you give an explanation about this sentence:

> the space of functions that are their own nth derivatives is n-dimensional, spanned by $e^{\omega x}$, where omega is an nth root of unity;

Or how to solve the equation $y^{(n)} = y$?

Comment: These are the solutions to the differential equation $$\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}-y=0.$$ This is a linear differential equation with constant coefficients to which the usual theory applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to see this fact, using a minimal amount of the theory of ordinary differential equations.

First, consider the polynomial $p(x)=x^n-1$. This polynomial factorizes into linear terms comprising the $n$th roots of unity. In particular, let $\omega$ be a primitive root $n$th root of unity, say $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ for concreteness. Then
$$p(x) = x^n - 1 = (x-1)(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)\cdots (x-\omega^{n-1}),$$
where the $n$ zeros of the polynomial $\{1,\omega,\omega^2,\cdots , \omega^{n-1}\}$ run through all the $n$th roots of unity.

The functions you want are the solutions to the differential equation
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}y(x) = y(x).$$
We can alternatively write this equation as
$$\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n} - 1\right)y(x) = p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)y(x) = 0.$$
Now, we know the factorization of $p(x)$, so we can write this as
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx} - 1\right)\left(\frac{d}{dx} - \omega\right)\cdots\left(\frac{d}{dx} - \omega^{n-1}\right)y(x) = 0.$$
Note that all the linear factors above commute, so there are $n$ obvious solutions, namely the solutions to the individual linear differential equations
$$\frac{d}{dx}y(x) = \omega^ky(x),$$
for $k=0,1,\cdots,n-1$. The solutions to these linear ODES are given by
$$y_k(x) = A_ke^{\omega^k x},$$
for some arbitrary constant $A_k$.

Since all the $n$th roots of unity are distinct, we now have $n$ linearly independent solutions. On the other hand, these must also be *all* the linearly independent solutions, since we know that any $n$th order ODE has precisely $n$ linearly independent solutions (this is a standard fact which I will not prove here). Therefore the most general solution is given by
$$y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_ke^{\omega^k x}.$$